# Efficiently counting the number of occurrences of strings in a file based on conditions

Tags: r

My aim is to count the number of occurrences of strings in a file depending on a condition in an efficient manner.

I have around 45k records in the input csv file. I need to read them all and create a new file that depicts the count of occurrences of the strings in the original file for a particular time duration.

**Input File:**

```
Timestamp              Field
7/13/2013 10:30         ABC
7/13/2013 11:30         ABC
7/13/2013 10:34         ABC    
7/13/2013 10:15         CDE
7/13/2013 10:00         ABC
7/13/2013 10:14         CDE
7/13/2013 12:30         ABC
7/13/2013 00:30         ABC
7/13/2013 07:30         CDE
```

The main goal is to count the field occurrences within a particular time slot.

The **output** I am expecting is:

```
Slots                           ABC                      CDE
7/13/2013 00:01-03:00            1                        0
7/13/2013 03:01-06:00            0                        0    
7/13/2013 06:01-09:00            0                        1
7/13/2013 09:01-12:00            4                        2
7/13/2013 12:01-15:00            1                        0    
7/13/2013 15:01-18:00            0                        0
7/13/2013 18:01-21:00            0                        0
7/13/2013 21:01-24:00            0                        0
```

I have written a brute force code that does my work, but it takes huge time to complete. 
I am looking for an efficient code to accomplish this task.

I have a separate data frame that holds the time slots(day_hour) and the field names(field_data). My brute force approach is to use two for loops to search among all the records of both the data frames and count the occurrences accordingly.

Please guide me if I can use functions like `table()` or something that can help in this scenario.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would first convert "Timestamp" to an actual time object, then use `cut` to create your three-hour intervals, and use `table` to get the output you are looking for:

```
mydf$Times <- strptime(mydf$Timestamp, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M")
mydf$Breaks <- cut(mydf$Times, "3 hours")
table(mydf$Breaks, mydf$Field)
#                      
#                       ABC CDE
#   2013-07-13 00:00:00   1   0
#   2013-07-13 03:00:00   0   0
#   2013-07-13 06:00:00   0   1
#   2013-07-13 09:00:00   4   2
#   2013-07-13 12:00:00   1   0
```

---

Here's some sample data to start with:

```
mydf <- structure(list(Timestamp = c("7/13/2013 10:30", "7/13/2013 11:30", 
    "7/13/2013 10:34", "7/13/2013 10:15", "7/13/2013 10:00", "7/13/2013 10:14", 
    "7/13/2013 12:30", "7/13/2013 00:30", "7/13/2013 07:30"), 
    Field = c("ABC", "ABC", "ABC", "CDE", "ABC", "CDE", "ABC", "ABC", "CDE")), 
    .Names = c("Timestamp", "Field"), 
    class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -9L))
```

---

You can also play around with "data.table" (at least version 1.8.11+) and use `dcast.data.table`. The steps area more or less the same.

```
library(data.table)
library(reshape2)
packageVersion("data.table")
# [1] ‘1.8.11’

DT <- data.table(mydf)
DT[, Times := as.POSIXct(strptime(Timestamp, "%m/%d/%Y %H:%M"))]
DT[, Grps := cut(Times, "3 hours")]
dcast.data.table(DT, Grps ~ Field, value.var="Field")
# 'Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
#                   Grps ABC CDE
# 1: 2013-07-13 00:00:00   1   0
# 2: 2013-07-13 06:00:00   0   1
# 3: 2013-07-13 09:00:00   4   2
# 4: 2013-07-13 12:00:00   1   0
```

Comment: Thank you so much. This is just what I wanted. :) The first three lines of the answer is simply what is needed, I didn't know how to use them properly. You gave me the exact way how to go about it. Thanks a lot once again :)

Comment: Your answer is inspiring when I recently cooked some data. Thank you.